# How can I put created_at and updated_at for all tables in Magento?

Tags: magento2

You can help me for how i can put `created_at` and `updated_at` in all tables quickly?

Thank you since now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an module called **CreatedUpdatedAt** with `etc/db_schema.xml` containing the follow content:

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="eav_attribute_set">
    <column name="created_at" nullable="false" xsi:type="datetime" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on_update="false"/>
    <column name="updated_at" nullable="true" xsi:type="datetime" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on_update="true"/>
</table>
```

For others tables only replicate.